# I need to create a formula where if a column has a value in it the entire row of that same value gets copied to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have been looking everywhere on different forums and help pages to assist me but I am completely novice to the world of scripts and macros and vba etc... Basically I have a sheet that has all the products our company carries, columns include; product name, cost, retail price, quantity and subtotal.  I want to be able to create the ability to copy an entire row where the quantity column is above 0.  Basically, we will input what the client wants including quantity and on another sheet it will be a condensed version of exactly what he ordered instead of the items that they did not order. This way we can just print off this sheet and hand it in to our production/ordering department instead of having them scroll through excel and see all the products they wanted and did not want.

Is this too complicated? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you kindly,

Sandra

Answer (score 0):

I answered an almost identical question here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/930240-how-do-you-pull-certain-info-from-one-worksheet-to-another-only-containing-certain-values.html

Hopefully  you can adapt the solution to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't need vba code. You can add 1 more column let's say "Clients order". Then you filling it up and filter not empty cells. Formula vlookup could also do the trick.

But if you want to use code I would do something like that:

1. In another sheet you should create headings in first row, like Product, Price, Quantity etc.
2. Row below the Product heading would be a list of products (use data validation)
3. Other cells in this row should have vlookup formula looking for information about product you choosed.
4. There also would be button with functionality of copying what's in the line and pasting it in the place you want (below this list, in another sheet etc.), here is example of such macro:

   ```
   Range("A2:C2").Select
   Selection.copy

   Rows("4:4").Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

   Range("A4").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   ```